# Image object error event not fired on 404

Tags: javascript, image

I wanted to write code to preload a bunch of images. I'm trying to count the number of failed loading attempts via the onerror eventhandler of the image object. However when the image is not found the event handler I'm assigning is not called for some reason (I remember 404 codes caused error events on image objects in the past and I haven't found anything contradictory during my research).

How can I find out that the image failed to load?

**Here my code** (the image url is deliberately wrong to trigger a 404):

```
var _img = new Image()
_img.addEventListener("error", function() {
    console.log("_img error")
}, false);
_img.src = "https://i.ytimg.com/test.jpg"
```

I also tried to use _img.onerror instead of _img.addEventListener(...) but the problem remains

**The HTTP headers:**

General

- Request URL: https://i.ytimg.com/test.jpg
- Request Method: GET
- Status Code: 404
- Remote Address: 172.217.19.214:443
- Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

- alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
- cache-control: public, max-age=30
- content-length: 1097
- content-type: image/jpeg
- date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 16:02:18 GMT
- expires: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 16:02:48 GMT
- server: sffe
- status: 404
- timing-allow-origin: https://imasdk.googleapis.com
- x-content-type-options: nosniff
- x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Request headers

- Referer: http://localhost/test/js/canvas/test1.htm
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: While it seems very scarcely documented, the `error` event for an image simply lets you know if an image was returned or not. The reason your `error` event isn't firing is because your response, despite a status of `404`, is still returning a valid image.

Comment: @TylerRoper thank you for your effort and your help. I'll work out an alternative way to solve this then